# I'm having problems with RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a site I'm trying to develop and I am having some (probably noob) problems getting my reWrite rules to work correctly.

Basically, I'm using the codeIgniter framework to develop the site and as part of this I have created a RewriteRule to remove the index.php part of the URL with the exception of some folders for images etc.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|shop)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /TESTSite/index.php/$1 [L]
```

The site originally has a current page of `page/facilities/our-shop` which was a very basic page with a few links to paypal to make a very rough shop page as we needed one quickly. However now I have implemented a different *(read OpenCart)* shop section to make this a bit more professional and allow more features etc. I have placed the openCart in a subdirectory called `shop`. The shop continues to work correctly as I've excluded the `/shop` from my original reWrite rule.

However - My problem... 
I want the old page `page/facilities/our-shop` to redirect to the `/shop` and therefore work as if I navigated directly there..

I have tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|shop)
RewriteRule ^page/facilities\/our-shop$  /TESTSite/shop/$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /TESTSite/index.php/$1 [L]
```

And

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|shop)
RewriteRule ^page/facilities\/our-shop$  /TESTSite/shop/$1 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /TESTSite/index.php/$1 [L]
```

And with a few other variations, but every time I can't get it to work. Can anyone advise please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule TESTSite/page/facilities/our-shop$  /TESTSite/shop/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|shop)
RewriteRule ^TESTSite/page/(.*)$ /TESTSite/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Two things:

- When you use `RewriteCond`, it only applies to the following rule. So I re-ordered the two lines.
- You do not need `\` before a `/` in a rule.

Check [this tool](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) to debug your rules.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume, I appreciate the response and help. Unfortunatly this still doesnt seem to do what I was expecting..

The page still stays on the original (old page). I entered the data into that tool you suggested and it gives the following:

`request = http://localhost/TESTSite/page/facilities/our-shop`

`.htaccess = 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/facilities/our-shop$  /TESTSite/shop/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|shop)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /TESTSite/index.php/$1 [L]`


`Output URL = http://localhost/TESTSite/page/facilities/our-shop`

Comment: The debug data on that site shows Line 1 and 2 output the lines of the rule, (line 3 blank), Line 4 gives:

`RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|shop) This variable is not supported: $`
Is the problem that I have a $? Should it be something different?
Line 5 says `This rule was not met because one of the conditions was not met`

Comment: You are right, answer edited. Sorry about, forgot about your root folder.